# How to use multiple "where like" in a relationship - Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have 4 tables in my DB. User , user_details, tags and taggables. By using the user table I am getting user along with user detail and tags. Following is table schema

```
Table user:
id, name, email, password

Table user_details
user_id, about, vision, picture

Table tags:
id, name

Table taggables
user_id, tag_id

here is my query:
User::with('userDetails','tags')->get();
```

I want to use where like in user name or tag name, How can I use multiple where like on user name and tag name????

Comment: using wherehas , you can read here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: I have the same column "name" of users and tags table, so how can I identify the name of table column

Comment: You should share some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
$users= User::with('userDetails','tags')
            ->where('name', 'LIKE',"%{$search}%")
            ->orWhereHas('tags', function($query) use($search) {
                $query->where('name','LIKE',"%{$search}%");
            })
            ->get();
```

**$search** is a variable here.